# How to hide the marker and zoom on a specified map location by clicking on the marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, openstreetmap, marker

I have a project to finish, and I have 1 month to finish it, I am very late…
I have tried to do what I want to have, but it never worked, I am a beginner in Javascript…
Here is what I would like to have in order to continue my project. Sorry in advance for my English…

I would like that, when I click on a country, markers appears (It works), but I would also like that when I click on a marker, this one disappear and zoom on a specified location (the river, to be precise).
And I also wanted that marker’s popup are shown on mouseover but I didn’t succeed.

I don’t know all the possibilities of javascript. But is it possible to see these things if I zoom out ? (for example : I see the river, I zoom out to the country level and markers appears)

A help would considerably help me in my project and hopefully allow me to finish in time.

Thank you for your attention,

Here is the link of my full code that works till before my last changes :
https://jsfiddle.net/Gio687351/cj9bvrg7/1/

Here is one of the codes that I have tested :

```js
function toggleLayerVisibility(map, selectedLayer) {
    if (selectedLayerId && selectedLayerId !== selectedLayer._leaflet_id) {
        map.eachLayer(layer => {
            if (layer._leaflet_id === selectedLayerId) geojson.resetStyle(layer);
        });
    }
    selectedLayer.setStyle({
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.0
        

    });
      
    selectedLayerId = selectedLayer._leaflet_id; //save identifier of a selected layer
    
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 8 && map.getZoom() > 6){
            map.removemarker;
    }
    else {
        map.on('zoomend', {
          marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {  
L.marker([52.7472, -8.5087]).bindPopup('Limerick, Shannon River').addTo(map);
L.marker([53.34565, -6.32105]).bindPopup('Dublin, River Liffey').addTo(map);
L.marker([47.88363, 7.22444]).bindPopup('Soultz-Haut-Rhin, Le Rimbach').addTo(map);        }
});  }  
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e9JC.png)

Comment: It would be better if you type the code instead of attaching an image for other users in case they have the same issue with you